how to use org.eclipse.cdt.utils.pty.PTY in eclipse 2024 03 version?
In eclipse 2019 version used in this class of CDT org.eclipse.cdt.utils.pty.PTY, specific method of use is as follows:
    boolean is*UsingPTY = ((properties.get("process") == null) &&(PTY.isSupported(PTY.Mode.TERMINAL)))
|| ((properties.get("pty") instanceof PTY));
boolean localEcho = false;
        if ((!properties.containsKey("localEcho")) || (!(properties.get("localEcho") instanceof Boolean))) {
            if ("win32".equals(Platform.getOS())) {
                localEcho = !isUsingPTY;
            }
        } else {
            localEcho = ((Boolean) properties.get("localEcho")).booleanValue();
        }
        String lineSeparator = null;
        if ((!properties.containsKey("lineSeparator")) || (!(properties.get("lineSeparator") instanceof String))) {
            if (!isUsingPTY) {
                lineSeparator = "win32".equals(Platform.getOS()) ? "\\r\\n" : "\\n";
            }
        } else {
            lineSeparator = (String) properties.get("lineSeparator");
        }
   ....................................

    PTY pty = (PTY) properties.get("pty");
    ProcessSettings processSettings = new ProcessSettings();
    processSettings.setPTY(pty);

Due to the use of the latest version of eclispe, cdt removed the pty class cannot be used, resulting in an error, how to solve it???
I tried to install an older version of cdt, but an error was still reported

org.eclipse.cdt.utils.pty.PTY still exists: https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/blob/main/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core.native/src/org/eclipse/cdt/utils/pty/PTY.java Please provide a complete minimal reproducible example and tell the exact error message you get. You might have overlooked some hints of deprecation by skipping so many versions, so you might check the history. You might also look in the source code of CDT how PTY is used nowadays: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aeclipse-cdt%2Fcdt%20%22new%20PTY(%22&type=code
